# Does Scala's JavaConverters produce incomplete result?

Tags: scala

Following code converts Scala `List` into `java.util.List` (Tested in Scala 2.11)

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val a = List(1, 2, 3)
val b = a.asJava
```

However, the conversion result seems incomplete. Because some methods in `java.util.List` do not work.

```
scala> b.remove(2)
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
  at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
  ... 29 elided
```

My workaround is as follows:

```
val c = new java.util.ArrayList(a.asJava)
```

This works but seems redundant in API-design perspective.

Is this the correct way of using `asJava` method?

Why does Scala's JavaConverters produce incomplete result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because some methods in `java.util.List` do not work.

These methods are explicitly optional, because `java.util.List` covers both mutable and immutable lists, and some of implementations in Java standard library don't support them either:

> > Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present (optional operation)...
> >
> > Throws: ... UnsupportedOperationException - if the remove operation is not supported by this list

Same for other Java collection interfaces. So the result *does* completely satisfy the interface.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that what you're getting from the asJava is an immutable list, as you've started with an immutable Scala list. Try the following

```
val a = List(1,2,3).to[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer].asJava
```

Comment: I think this should be the default action of asJava method. Anyway, there's a typo in your code: `mutable.ListBuffer`

Comment: This cannot be the default action, because all of the adapter interfaces are views - they do not result into new collections being created but expose the original collections instead. Since the original collection is immutable, the derived one will be as well.